# Raspberry Pi4 with only linux kernel

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, kernel

I'm making a robotics project where I have really limited power and heating problems. All I want to do is run a single C++ code on it.

I don't want a whole operating system just for that task. So I thought I would just do baremetal register programming, but the project has a bit more functionality than I first assumed and I'm forced to use some libraries, mainly vulkan and onnxruntime.

Now, my question is, can I run raspberry pi 4b with a linux kernel only without an OS and run a single piece of code that has vulkan and onnxruntime on it? If so, how can I do it? Is there any good tutorials / datasheets on the internet I can follow? Or will vulkan and onnxruntime work without linux kernel if I compile them for the right architecture so I do baremetal programming?

Comment: For a minimal Linux system, you could use the Linux kernel with Busybox, your single userspace application, and required libraries. A library could be purely userspace, e.g. routines to perform complicated calculations, or could provide a convenient API to system capabilities, e.g. GUI functions, that will make system calls to the kernel. Suggest you look at/use Buildroot for configuring a small/minimal Linux system. BTW you're probably underestimating what you give up w/o the Linux kernel if you go baremetal.

Comment: Your question has some good elements, but it is also asking multiple questions, and a couple of those questions are either answered by a web search or by "have you tried it yourself yet". Please EDIT your question to focus on a single specific question, and in that question show your research and what you've tried so far to help those who may have answers for you.

Comment: @music2myear Attie already answered my question(s) which helped me a lot. Maybe instead of making this comment help like everyone else did.

Comment: @Turgut As an asker it is normal to think the purpose of your question is to benefit you, but the purpose of this site is to benefit others as, through our own individual questions being answered a compendium of solutions is built and improved. Failing to meet the conventions of this site means your question does not benefit others in the way this site expects. To put it another way: your question would be closed on its own, but because Attie focused on a single aspect of your question and gave a good answer, it may survive. Fixing your question will help others and make it a better site fit.

Comment: @music2myear I understand the wiki-esque part of the site where a question becomes a staple part in everyone's journey to find an answer, but not every question can be constructed in such a way. A simple web search, which I have done before, did not provide me with the information provided in the answers. "Have you tried it" is completely redundant here since the entire purpose of the question is the fact that I am incapable of trying it myself. I would have done what ChatGPT told me if it wasn't a specific, ambiguous question which required an equally ambiguous answer.

Comment: @music2myear As this might provide some useful info to someone else, I needed to ask the question in such a way that it becomes "Here is what I know please help me fill in the blanks" is because it's a situation where I should be steered in a direction within the confines of my own knowledge as I don't want to learn an entirely new concept/library when I already know some before hand, such as vulkan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) and [Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/)... they're designed to produce very small embedded systems, customised to your use-case, and with the specific packages you require... While you *could* use just a Linux kernel with an built-in / hand-rolled initramfs, that's not a straightforward project unless you're very comfrotable with what's involved - especially given your mention of Vulcan and ONNX Runtime.

With a system as large and complex as a Raspberry Pi, I'd strongly recommend you keep the Linux kernel and do not pursue "*baremetal register programming*" - you'll almost certainly be less power efficient than Linux, and you'll loose out on *a lot* of the work that's already been done to make the system useful - from getting the second core running, to managing interrupts and drivers for peripherals, etc... "*getting it to run*" will be a large project in itself.

If "*getting a Pi to do something useful **without Linux***" is a ***major*** part of your project, and something you have good support in achieving, then have at it!

Comment: Given the OP's penchant for a minimalist system, the mention of Yocto seems misguided. Not sure why you think an initramsfs is so complicated when it really isn't. E.G. I've done it manually, before there was a Buildroot that made it truly trivial.

Comment: @sawdust Sure, Yocto will likely produce a larger image than Buildroot, but it'll still smaller than many off-the-shelf options like PiOS and can squeezed... A basic initramfs isn't so hard, but OP mentioned Vulkan and ONNX Runtime, which will likely lead to a rapid increase in dependencies, possibly firmware (and loading thereof), etc... Unless having absolute control over the image and counting bytes was important to me (and I had the time), I wouldn't choose to hand-roll an initramfs - I'd prefer to get as much as possible for "_free_", and have a reproducible and easily tweakable image!

Comment: @Attie Great! Guess I'll look at either Yocto or just strap a linux kernel and get on with it. I think I can compile ONNX and Vulkan for a simple linux kernel. Thanks!